# Do we need a general reference question for "ReferenceError: libraryName is not defined"?

Tags: discussion, canonical

There are lots of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions on SO, where OP is using some library, for example jQuery, and is getting following error:

> ReferenceError: *libraryName* is not defined

Some examples:

- [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)
- [Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined from restangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283622/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-from-restangular)
- [What is the cause for "angular is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044519/what-is-the-cause-for-angular-is-not-defined)
- [Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175729/uncaught-referenceerror-cordova-is-not-defined)
- [Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined at angular-moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150576/uncaught-referenceerror-angular-is-not-defined-at-angular-moment-js)
- [Google Maps API: markerwithlabel.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692791/google-maps-api-markerwithlabel-js-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-def)

This error is usually caused by one of the following:

- not including the library file at all,
- including scripts in wrong order (i.e. using a script which depends on the library before including the library).

That makes all these questions duplicates, because there is one solution to all of them. So, I think we need a general reference question for such questions, which would apply to any JavaScript library and provide full, comprehensive, canonical answer.

It seems that [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined) a question which could be considered a general reference, but it's only about jQuery. It rather wouldn't be a good idea to close a question about, for example, Underscore.js as a duplicate of it.

Comment: Should we really be closing such questions as dupes? Shouldn't we close them as *simple typographical errors* instead?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would agree that it's a simple typographical error, but this is certainly not an error which can't be reproduced, because people still ask such questions.

Comment: Technically, it cannot be reproduced as soon as the missing reference is added. But yes, this close reason is a little... schizoid. On the other hand, I don't believe that, say, the C++ folks have a canonical for *You forgot to include `<iostream>`*.

Comment: Could be.  Write it.