# Should questions resolved by missing JavaScript files be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have encountered multiple questions that were solved because the user forgot to include something like jQuery or [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) in their code.

In the past I've attempted to close these kinds of questions due to the fact that they are not helpful to any future users, but my requests aged away.

Shouldn't these kinds of questions be closed using the **simple typographical error** option?

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced**
>   or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely
>   inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
>   before posting.

Comment: dupe closure works too

Comment: *but my requests aged away* I think that just means no one acted on it on time, not that the flag was wrong in any way.

Comment: Dupe is much better.  If a generic enough question for this doesn't exist ask one.  Then you can close all others as dupes.  See how null pointer exception questions are handled.

Comment: *If a generic enough question for this doesn't exist ask one.* @CandiedOrange How would that not get a ton of down votes though?

Comment: By asking it well and seeing to it that it is answered well (you can answer it yourself).  It's ok to make clear the intent is to create a place to send frequent nearly identical questions about the same issue in the question.  Link in a few examples, at least in comments.  You can also develop the idea in meta first to be sure you're dealing with all the relevant cases.

Comment: I'm not sure a canonical works well for this, but it probably depends on the library. For example, Stack Overflow answerers seem to be under the impression that jQuery ships natively with browsers now and that any JavaScript question in theory can be answered with jQuery - a canonical could be useful in reminding people that you do in fact need to include a copy of jQuery yourself.

Comment: @BoltClock - Are you suggesting that we create a [needs more jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) canonical post?

Comment: As pointed out in the question, these posts are unlikely to be helpful for future user. What are the chances that someone else get the exact same symptoms as OP ? If we talk about something like `$ is undefined`, then a simple request on any search engine will give the answer. What the actual post will add to all the 15000 already there ? I really don't see what is the benefit of marking it as duplicate.

Comment: Related: [Do we need a general reference question for “ReferenceError: libraryName is not defined”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315473/3853934)

Comment: If you've encountered "multiple questions", then it seems like they might have been "helpful to [..,] future users" (assuming, of course, that they could find them).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, that is the proper close reason. I usually downvote these, vote to close as you indicate, and then move on with my day. Hopefully the point gets across.

The issue with trying to point these to a duplicate is that there are far too many ways to get this type of problem to cover in one post. Not to mention that creating canonical posts is very hard in general. For example, I have a gold tag badge for JavaScript, and I am not sure what the canonical should look like here.

Keep in mind questions should be closed because their question is a duplicate, not because the answer would also fit to that question.

> Remember: duplicates are questions that ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems - many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates. By the same token, many questions are asked using very different wordings but seek to solve identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a solution even when they don't know what terms to search for. -[Tim Post♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/178816)

So, to sum this up, what you are doing is the right course of action. Perhaps creating a duplicate target for these is an option - but getting it right is very hard.

Comment: True, never said it would be easy.  Just better.

Comment: Yes, this. And please please please remember to downvote - if there aren't any answers, the downvote will cause that question to be automatically deleted in about 30 days.

Comment: I wish there was a way to request a notification when a question is edited.  Then I could downvote and not feel the need to hover over the question in case it improves.  I know I don't have to.  It'd just make me feel like downvoting more.

Comment: Another thing to consider is questions closed as a duplicate do not get auto deleted like other closed question.  If the questions adds nothing to the site then closing it for a non dupe close reason allows the roomba to do its work and keeps the site cleaner.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I agree. Having a sort of "junk" canonical to close these as duplicates with would only create a large chain of junk posts and may hamper their removal if they are not adding anything to the site.

Comment: @NathanOliver the point of closing as dupe and not deleting is of course to hack google.  The real value of a dupe is the searchable terms in the title.  It's only clutter if it's not click bait.